# Combobox no showing options

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a simple reusable component as:

**TS**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() options: [];
  @Input() idAndForAttributes: string;
  @Input() customClass: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'invalid': control.invalid && control.touched && control.dirty}">
  <label [attr.for]="idAndForAttributes">{{ label }}:</label>
  <select class="form-control" [ngClass]="customClass" [formControl]="control" [attr.id]="idAndForAttributes">
    <option value="0">- Select -</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of options" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.description}}</option>
  </select>
  <ng-container *ngIf="control.dirty && control.touched && control.invalid">
    <div *ngIf="control.errors.required || (control.errors.min && control.value == 0)">
      <small style="color: #c62828;">
        Value is required.
      </small>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to use it in my other html as:

```
   <form [formGroup]="profileActivityForm">
     <app-select [control]="profileActivityForm.get('activityType')" [idAndForAttributes]="'type'" [label]="'Type'"
                [options]="profileActivityTypes"></app-select>
   </form>
```

Then in **TS**

```
 profileActivityTypes: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileActivityTypes.push('New')
    this.profileActivityTypes.push('Update')

 this.profileActivityForm = this.fb.group({
 activityType: [0]
    });
  }
```

But it is showing invisible options like the following picture:

[image]

I think the problem is on the html of the reusable component `<option *ngFor="let item of options" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.description}}</option>`

Because it is looking for a description, how can I send the item as a description from the child component?

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
  profileActivityTypes: [] = [];
  ....

let profileActivities = [{ description: 'New' }, { description: 'Update' }]
this.profileActivityTypes.push(profileActivities)
```

but it is throwing an error on push:

> Argument of type '{ description: string; }[]' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'never'

Comment: your options is a string[] `profileActivityTypes: string[] = [];` and you are trying to use id and description inside the html option so you are accessing it like an object.

Comment: Yes, I tried the last part of my question: but I can not form the object correctly @NathanT.

Comment: you still need to add an id to your objects `let profileActivities = [{ id:1,description: 'New' }, {id:2, description: 'Update' }]`

Comment: I tried but getting on the push line the following error: Argument of type '{ id: number; description: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. @NathanT.

Comment: try changing `@Input() options: [];` to `@Input() options: any[];`

Comment: Now it does not throw the error, but it is not showing the value of the description again, and now instead of trying to show 2 options as photo, it apparently only appear one @NathanT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251533/discussion-between-nathan-t-and-jesus).

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, I changed the assignation of the `profileActivities`  array instead of creating the array and then pushing it. I assign it directly as:

```
 profileActivityTypes = [];
   this.profileActivityTypes = [{ id: 1, description: 'New' }, {id: 2, description: 'Update'}]
```

I hope this works for more people!

Comment: It's related to [strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode#strict-mode). You should define your profileActivityTypes like `profileActivityTypes:{id:number,description:string}[]=[]`